# setting session variables in grails 1.3.7

Tags: session, grails, scope

I have a question that will probably have a very simple solution. I'm running grails 1.3.7 and I'm trying to set a session variable like: `session["username"] = uName` where uName is a value returned from a database query.

The problem I'm having is that the keyword `session` seems to be not recognized by grails (it's underlined). Further, when I actually try to run the app I get this error: `No such property: session for class:`.

I don't have any imports, should I?

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Inside a controller?

Comment: oops forgot to say where I was calling it from, it's from a domain class not a controller... let me guess... you can't store sessions in controllers.

Comment: sorry you cant store sessions in domain classes***

Comment: I think I should be able to approve/disapprove any edits made on my own posts. I understand the value of edits, however I feel that the OP should be notified and able to decide whether or not to keep the edit or to fix it to their own words. Changing I'm to I am is just plain nit picking, it's the way I write and it isn't wrong in this context. I'm not writing in a very professional setting. If I were, I would have skipped the contraction of the words.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing. When you have enough reputation points, you will be able to approve/decline edits, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have the `session` variable available to you in controllers, taglibs and GSPs, not in services or domain classes.  You can always access it via the thread-local holder, but bear in mind that you only have a session if the current thread is a request handler (i.e. not if it's a background thread):

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

def currentRequest = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes
if(currentRequest) { // we have been called from a web request processing thread
  // currentRequest is an instance of GrailsWebRequest
  currentRequest.session["uName"] = ...
} else {
  // not in a request handler thread, so no session available
}
```

but it's generally better to keep logic that requires access to the HTTP request in controllers (or taglibs) where you know that you will always have a "current request".

Answer (score 0):

saving session variables have to be done in controllers not domain classes.  thanks to @Igor Artamonov for his useful comment.